# Cannot insert into Appcelerator database

Tags: database, insert, appcelerator

I am developing an iOS app in Appcelerator (SDK 1.7.2). I am trying to save the content of a API call (JSON) into a local database on the device. I am using the code below but no posts are saved. The insert statement works fine outside the loop. I am working in a single context app if that has anything to do with it.

```
    // Open the DB connection

    var db = Titanium.Database.open('thedatabase');

    // Create tables if they do not exist

    db.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (contact_id INTEGER, token TEXT, fullname VARCHAR, message TEXT, datetime VARCHAR, avatar TEXT, favorite INTEGER)');

    // Get the data

    Xhr.GET ({resource: 'contacts/all.json?'}, function (json) {

        // Loop trough the JSON response

        for (var i = 0; i < json.contacts.length; i++) {

            // Insert contact to the database

            db.execute('INSERT INTO contacts (contact_id, token, fullname, message, datetime, avatar, favorite) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', '0','1','2','3','4','5','6');

        }

    });

    // Close the database

    db.close();
```

Comment: An old question, but nevertheless an important tip: please do not cross-post without attribution. Online communities tend to think of this as rather anti-social, because the separate threads can encourage disparate volunteer groups to create duplicate help, thus wasting the time of volunteers. Not [cross-posting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_posting) without acknowledging the other threads has been part of netiquette for around 25 years, and it is certainly not a guideline that has originated from Stack Overflow. Hope that is helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community is already helping you locate the answer over on Q&A: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/125036/cannot-insert-into-database